# How to stop 3d touch its interrupt other touch events?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I have a view with `touchesMoved` event in current `UIViewController` , when touch move in screen it will draw something (free draw)

then I add a `subView` in the view and bind the UITapGestureRecognizer(set numberOfTapsRequired 2) with subview,
If double click is detect I will move the UIImageView to the click position.
When I try to draw again, something wrong is happen, the draw line is not smooth now (some line is not display)

Because of the 3D Touch in iPhone6s and 6s Plus, So I can't detect the tapCount in `touchesEnded`.What Shall I do?

Comment: How to off the 3D Touch with code?  @Kishore Kumar

Comment: see my answer ..,i will try to give more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is stop the 3d touch while your app is launched :

As per the apple documentation you can see this here :[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH4-SW1)

A user can turn off 3D Touch while your app is running, so read this property as part of your implementation of the traitCollectionDidChange: delegate method.

To ensure that all your users can access your app’s features, branch your code depending on whether 3D Touch is available. When it is available, take advantage of 3D Touch capabilities. When it is not available, provide alternatives such as by employing touch and hold, implemented with the UILongPressGestureRecognizer class.

Refer to iOS Human Interface Guidelines for ideas on how to enhance your app’s interactions for users with 3D Touch-capable devices while not leaving your other users behind.

BEST CODE:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress;
For backward compatibility I’ll also add a long press gesture recogniser here. Should our sample app be run on a device without 3D Touch support, at least the preview can be brought up via a long press gesture.

We’ll check if 3D Touch is available using something like the following method. To complete the setup, I’ve also included a custom initialiser for the long press gesture.

    - (void)check3DTouch {

        // register for 3D Touch (if available)
        if (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable) {

            [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:(id)self sourceView:self.view];
            NSLog(@"3D Touch is available! Hurra!");

            // no need for our alternative anymore
            self.longPress.enabled = NO;

        } else {

            NSLog(@"3D Touch is not available on this device. Sniff!");

            // handle a 3D Touch alternative (long gesture recognizer)
            self.longPress.enabled = YES;

            }
    }

    - (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPress {

        if (!_longPress) {
            _longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showPeek)];
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_longPress];
        }
        return _longPress;
    }
```

Comment: Still don't know how to disable 3D Touch functionality when app is running.

Comment: @ChrisForever what problem your are facing ?

Comment: @ChrisForever go a head step by step ,check your protocol implementation and all ,then check if and else statement is working or not.

Comment: This solution is to skip off the 3D Touch on iPhone 6s/6s plus, and use another method to answer the uitouch events. However, I just want to disable 3D Touch when my app is running. Is there a possible way to do that? Thanks